# Redirecting thousands of deprecated product QR codes

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, react-router, vue-router

I'm in a bind where a client has thousands of printed QR codes derived from a record ID like `website.com/item/someOldRecordId` and the URLs are deprecated because of a DB change that resulted in new record IDs for all the rows. i.e. the existing deprecated QR codes images need to take people to `website.com/item/someNewRecordId` when scanned.

The only way I can think to accomplish this redirect is to query the DB in the router for every entry URL that contains `/item/`, then grab the id and see if it's new or old, then fetch the new record ID, build the new URL and then redirect. This feels *awfully* slow and janky.

Is there an elegant solution?

**TL;DR**

My feeling is that building this kind of logic into a Router is an ugly hack and probably more expensive than just paying people to re-print and replace a few thousand QR codes(?)

Comment: I would suggest to treat this as `301` redirects and map old to new ids rather than looking each of them up. (I assume you have the list of old ids and a list of new ids) And with `301` you get to sort them into its own file

Comment: From where I sit, the router sounds like the perfect place to manage these redirects, but if you're of the mindset that the router level should be agnostic towards the data in your application, then I can see why you might want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ugly hack, but probably much cheaper than to print and relabel thousands of items. Even worse if this is supposed to help customers check for items they already own.

But why do this at the router, and not just in the application code? If the QR code turns out to be obsolete, look up and return the information for the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that might feel less "hacky" would be implementing a cache of some sort on top of the manual lookups.

The gist is that only the first hit would need to look up the conversion, and subsequent hits would be able to pull the known result faster.

In theory, this functionality could live at any level of your application, or even be implemented into the database directly if you wanted to go that far, but it could save some lookups and improve return speeds in the meantime because you wouldn't have to do the full lookup on every call.